# posts_nav_link() not working on index.php

Tags: loop, pagination, navigation

I have a problem with the `posts_nav_link()` function on index.php. It works but it's not displaying the older posts. When someone clicks on the "next page" link the same posts from the fist page are loading.

This is the code I'm using:

```
<?php if ( is_home ()) {$myquery = new wp_query('cat=-41');}?> 
<?php
    global $wp_query;
    $temp_wp_query = $wp_query;
    $wp_query = null;
    $wp_query = $myquery;
?>      
    <!-- Start the look -->
    <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_title();?>
        <?php
         if( has_post_thumbnail()) { 
            the_post_thumbnail('article-thumb'); }
         ?>
         <?php the_author_posts_link();?>
                     <?php the_category(', ');?>
                     <?php the_time('j F, Y'); ?>.
         <?php the_excerpt();?>
         <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">Citeste mai departe</a>       
          <?php endwhile; ?>          
          <?php else : ?>
            <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>           
          <?php endif; ?><!-- End the loop -->
          <?php posts_nav_link( ' ', '<img src="' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/img/pagina-precedenta.png" align="left" />', '<img src="' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/img/pagina-urmatoare.png" align="right" />' ); ?>  
          <?php $wp_query = $temp_wp_query;?>
```

The `posts_nav_link()` function works properly on the `category.php`, only on `index.php` I have this problem and it's definitely related to my custom loop but I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `paged=` paramter.

```
$myquery = new wp_query('cat=-41&paged=' . get_query_var( 'page' ));
```

> **Codex Note -** You should set `get_query_var( 'page' )` if you want your query to work with pagination.

- **Tip** - If you want to eclude a category from main page you can use the `pre_get_post` filter. That is better way to - [Exclude categories from main page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#Example:_Exclude_categories_on_your_main_page)

### Update -

Drop in this code in your theme's `functions.php` and remove all that your customization from top of loop. *(7 lines)*

```
function wpse61695_exclude_cat( $query )  {

    // making sure it runs on home page and on main query
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    
        $query->set( 'cat', '-41' );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse61695_exclude_cat' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer amit. I've added the `get_query_var( 'page' )` to the `wp_query` but it's still not working. I've also tried it without the `cat=-41` but I got the same behavior.

Comment: using `pre_get_post` hook will not break the pagination. And you don't even need to modify the loop this way.

Comment: OK, I'll try to do it with `pre_get_post` - now reading about how to implement it. Thanks!

Comment: hm, I've updated answer with instruction and code,

Comment: Thanks, do I need to call the `add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse61695_exclude_cat' );` somewhere in my `index.php`? I'm asking this because the posts from category ID 41 are still showing up on my homepage.

Comment: no just put that in your functions.php file

Comment: remove 7 lines before `<!-- Start the look -->`  and last one

Comment: That's exactly what I did but I still see the posts from the category with ID 41.

Comment: oops I think I missed to return $query;